# Get PouchDB attachment?

Tags: javascript, html, database, pouchdb

I am trying to create a site where I can ask questions and answer them. In order to do this, I have two files, one that sends the question to the database, and the other that outputs the attachment of each `docs` in which the question is.

Post.js :

```
db.post({
    title: 'question'
}).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response)
    q = response
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});

await sleep(100)
console.log(q.rev)

var attachment = new Blob([{
    "title" : title,
    "content" : content,
    "option" : option,
    "spec" : spécialisation,
    "year" : year,
    "date" : date}, {type: 'text/json'}]);
db.putAttachment(q.id.toString(),'qData', q.rev.toString(), attachment, 'text/json')
.then(function (result) {
    console.log(result)
})
.catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

And view.js :

```
var all = db.allDocs({
}).then(function (result) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result.rows))
    return result.rows
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

But I can't get it to work, it outputs no error and the single ouput that I receive is a doc without any attachment.
What is my (probably newbish) error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add following options to your `allDocs` call:

```
{
  include_docs: true,
  attachments: true
}
```

Quoting the [docs](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#batch_fetch) on those two options:

> `options.include_docs`: Include the document itself in each row in the
>   doc field. Otherwise by default you only get the _id and _rev
>   properties.
>
> `options.attachments`: Include attachment data as base64-encoded string.

The docs have a full example, which should return your attachments as base64 string:

```
db.allDocs({
  include_docs: true,
  attachments: true
}).then(function (result) {
  // handle result
}).catch(function (err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

---

Note: I see your working with Blobs. Take a look at this option if you'd rather get your attachments as a Blob than a base64 string:

> `options.binary`: Return attachment data as Blobs/Buffers, instead of as
>   base64-encoded strings.